# IllegalArgument: javax.inject-Extension-Name when deploying webapp

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, inject

I am getting the exception below when launching Tomcat 7.0.54 with my web app. This same webapp launches fine when running tomcat through Eclipse. I initially deployed as a war file, then as a exploded war. The exception is only seen when not running in Eclipse. I have tried it on multiple platforms.

I thought this could be a result of the javax.inject libs not being in the tomcat classpath when it is parsing through the manifest files, so I added the javax.inject.jar file to the tomcat lib directory... same deal. I actually cannot find in any file the argument value "javax-inject-Extension-Name".

Has anyone seen this, or have a suggestion?

Thanks.

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/rdf.service]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.inject-Extension-Name
    at java.util.jar.Attributes$Name.<init>(Attributes.java:464)
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.getValue(Attributes.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ManifestResource.getRequiredExtensions(ManifestResource.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ManifestResource.processManifest(ManifestResource.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ManifestResource.<init>(ManifestResource.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being with a dependent jar that I had pulled off of github, and had built with maven. That pom file specified the option to addExtensions when building the jar with the maven jar plugin. One of the extensions was javax.inject... however, the maven jar plugin turns this into java_inject-Extension-Name, but leaves it as javax.inject in the Extensions-List... this disconnect is what caused the issue.

When running in eclipse, it must not be doing this same verification. Rebuilding the jar without the extensions in the Manifest.mf file fixed the issue.